# Java Selenium does not loaded my Page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem, if I open a website with Selenium Webdriver (Java), this website doesn't appear.
Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.de/");
```

And the result in the InternetExplorer:
"The Following Website can't load"
And the URL in the InternetExplorer is: "http://--port=48184/" and not "https://www.google.de/".

Comment: what is your selenium and IE version?

Comment: I tried it with selenium 3.0.1 and selenium 2.5.1. Both of them didn't worked. IE Version is Eclipse Neon.2( the newest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

instead?

`driver.get(webAddress)` is what is used most commonly to open a website.

Comment: The driver.navigate().to() method just calls driver.get() method. Both are identical. Check out the private class RemoteNavigation - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java